# Makefile equivalent in CMake

Tags: cmake

I have just started using CMake and it has been less than a week. I have a Makefile written and I am trying to write its equivalent in CMake. I don't have an idea about the commands that I should use in CMake for each of the statements in the given Makefile. How do I get started? Is there some place I can find documentation for this?

Answer (score 10):

I just converted my project (~15000 lines of C++ code, builds shared libraries, unit tests, and executables) to CMake from scons a couple of weeks ago, and it only took a day or two to do.

One thing I found helpful was that the [Boost project](http://www.boost.org/) now has experimental support for CMake rather than bjam. Looking through their code (specifically, the macros defined in `tools/build/CMake`) taught me a lot about some of the syntax and capabilities of CMake.

Also useful:

- The [official CMake FAQ](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ)
- The [online CMake documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake2.6docs.html)
- A [simple CMake tutorial](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6700)
- A quick overview of the [language/syntax](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/CMake/Language_Syntax)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can I ask you why did you decide against scons? I'm currently trying out build tools and scons is my next target.

Comment: Scons works well for very small projects working on a single platform. Its capabilities to automatically adjust the build process to different architectures (i.e., enabling certain flags on x86_64) was limiting to the point of frustration. There were other things, too; for example, adding build options (choose path to this framework, enable this compiler definition) was hideous in scons and simple in cmake.

Answer (score 1):

You should really subscribe to CMake mailling list ([here](http://www.cmake.org/mailman/listinfo/cmake)) and look at their [website](http://www.cmake.org/) in the "help" section, it's great!

If you don't find the answer to your question with some google research, or looking at the mailing list archive ([here](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/)), then just mail it to the mailing list and nice people will help you!

That's what I did about 2 month ago and now I've got a nice project compiling with cmake! :)